# How to align dropdown under parent control and set width as per parent control in bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

[image: Dropdown Menu Picture]

I tried to add `dropdown-menu-left` class but still it displayed outside the control area.
I want to show that dropdownlist under txtbox and button control, and also width as per
above control. How to do that?

Here is a demo `link` [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/oxb2nv6w/)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you misunderstood `dropdown-menu-right` for `dropdown-menu-left`. Replace `dropdown-menu-left` with `dropdown-menu-right`. As for the width, you could manually set it to a fixed value (using CSS) or you could use javascript / jquery to resize it dynamically. 
Using CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/7w9wkr64/ 
Using JQuery: https://jsfiddle.net/Lyrzt8tu/